# JQuery/Javascript/d3 'on click' functionality not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

So, basically I've got 2 circles: circle1 and circle2 that have been drawn using d3. By default, circle1 appears and when it is clicked, it shows the div: 'Circle1 has been clicked'. On clicking the next button, circle2 appears and I want it to display the div: 'Circle2 has been clicked' when I click on circle2(this is the part that doesn't work).

```
<div class="questions">
    <div id="canvas1" class="v1"style="width:200px; height:135px;">Circle1</div>
    <div id="div1" class="clickable" style="display:none;">You clicked Circle1</div>
</div>

<div class="questions">
    <div id="canvas2" class="v1"style="width:200px; height:135px;">Circle2</div>
    <div id="div2" class="clickable" style="display:none;">You clicked circle2</div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="next" value="Next" onclick="sum_value()">
```

Javascript code:

```
var totalQuestions = $('.questions').size();
var currentQuestion = 0;
$questions = $('.questions');
$questions.hide();
$($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
var nee = $('#next').click(function(){
  $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeOut(function(){
    currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
    if(currentQuestion == totalQuestions){
      alert('You have reached the end!');
    } else {
      $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
    }
  });
});

   var msg = (function(){
    return function(){
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
        $("#div1").show();
    }
})();

var whole = d3.selectAll('.v1');
    var wholeCanvas = whole.append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 135);
wholeCanvas.append("circle").attr("cx", 50)
                            .attr("cy", 50)
                            .attr("r", 40)
                            .on("click", msg);

//want something like this
//var msg = (function(){
//      if(questions)[0]
//    return function(){
//        d3.event.stopPropagation();
//        $("#div1").show();
//    }
//          else if(questions)[1]
//      return function(){
//        d3.event.stopPropagation();
//        $("#div2").show();
//    }
// })();
```

working fiddle so far: https://jsfiddle.net/La6w0pxy/

I know it can be done by attaching the circle(d3 object)to the divs separately(and hence svg's) and calling two separate functions. What I want to know is that, can it not be done by using an if statement as commented out below?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I suppose I was thinking on the wrong lines. The following two approaches worked for me:
First(by assigning id):

```
var whole = d3.select("#canvas1");
var wholeCanvas = whole.append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 135);
wholeCanvas.append("circle").attr("cx", 50)
                            .attr("cy", 50)
                            .attr("r", 40)
                            .attr("id", 'hey');

var whole2 = d3.select("#canvas2");
var whole2Canvas = whole2.append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 135);
whole2Canvas.append("circle").attr("cx", 50)
                            .attr("cy", 50)
                            .attr("r", 40)
                            .attr("id", 'hey2');

$("#hey").on("click", function(){
    $("#div1").show();
});

$("#hey2").on("click", function(){
    $("#div2").show();
});
```

Updated fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/La6w0pxy/4/

Second(without assigning id):

```
var whole = d3.select("#canvas1");
var wholeCanvas = whole.append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 135);
wholeCanvas.append("circle").attr("cx", 50)
                            .attr("cy", 50)
                            .attr("r", 40)
                            .on("click", function(d){
                            $("#div1").show();
                            });

var whole2 = d3.select("#canvas2");
var whole2Canvas = whole2.append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 135);
whole2Canvas.append("circle").attr("cx", 50)
                            .attr("cy", 50)
                            .attr("r", 40)
                            .on("click", function(d){
                            $("#div2").show();
                            });
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/La6w0pxy/5/